# Error provide a default value

Tags: mongodb, symfony

I'm trying to play with MongoDB. But I've got some problems.

```
# src/Controller/DefaultController.php
public function editCategoryAction(Category $category) {
    echo $category->getName();
    die();
}
```

With "entity" this is ok but not with MongoDB.

It displays this error message :

> Controller "Site\StoreBundle\Controller\DefaultController::editCategoryAction()" requires that you provide a value for the "$category" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).

My Category Document :

```
namespace Site\StoreBundle\Document;

use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as MongoDB;

/**
 * @MongoDB\Document
 */
class Category
{
    /**
     * @MongoDB\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\String
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @MongoDB\ReferenceMany(targetDocument="Product")
     */
    private $products = array();

    public function __contructor() {
        $this->products = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();   
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return id $id
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return self
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string $name
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getProducts() {
        return $this->products;
    }
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Add product
     *
     * @param Site\StoreBundle\Document\Product $product
     */
    public function addProduct(\Site\StoreBundle\Document\Product $product)
    {
        $this->products[] = $product;
    }

    /**
     * Remove product
     *
     * @param Site\StoreBundle\Document\Product $product
     */
    public function removeProduct(\Site\StoreBundle\Document\Product $product)
    {
        $this->products->removeElement($product);
    }
}
```

My Route

```
editCategory:
    path:  /editCategory/{id}
    defaults: { _controller: SiteStoreBundle:Default:editCategory }
```

How can I solve this ?

**Edit**:
I found this article : http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/10/symfony2-mongodb-odm-adding-the-missing-paramconverter/

I changed my *src/Site/StoreBundle/Resources/config/services.yml* to this :
    parameters:
    #    site_store.example.class: Site\StoreBundle\Example

```
services:
    doctrine_mongo_db_param_converter:
        class: Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\DoctrineParamConverter
        arguments: ['@doctrine_mongodb']
```

But same error :/

Comment: I assume you use `ParamConverter`, right?

Comment: Yes like this : public `function editCategoryAction(Category $category)`

Comment: Yes, how did you configure this method to use `ParamConverter`? Did you use YAML or XML to do it?

Comment: With my YAML i think. I followed this tutorial : http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/10/symfony2-mongodb-odm-adding-the-missing-paramconverter/ (check my **edit:**). I never had this bug with entities.

Comment: I have added the answer about service tag. You should try that first :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed to tag your service:

```
services:
    doctrine_mongo_db_param_converter:
        class: Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Request\ParamConverter\DoctrineParamConverter
        arguments: ['@doctrine_mongodb']
        tags:
            - { name: request.param_converter, priority: -2, converter: doctrine_mongo_db_param_converter}
```